# How to install node binary distribution files on Linux

Tags: linux, node.js

My production server (Centos 5.9) won't compile nodejs, possibly because it's gcc is only 4.1.2 (4.2 or above is recommended) so I've trying to install the binaries.

```
$ wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.22/node-v0.10.22-linux-x86.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf node-v0.10.22-linux-x86.tar.gz
$ cd node-v0.10.22-linux-x86
$ sudo cp bin/* /usr/local/bin
$ sudo cp -R lib/* /usr/local/lib
$ sudo cp -R share/* /usr/local/share
```

And now for testing:

```
$ node -v  # => v0.10.22
$ man node # looks fine
$ npm -v   # UH OH, PROBLEM - Cannot find module 'npmlog'
```

Now (keeping in mind I'm a complete beginner at node) I did some searching and found there's an environment variable called NODE_PATH, so I tried:

```
$ export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules
$ npm -v   # SAME PROBLEM - Cannot find module 'npmlog'
```

So then I found out where npmlog lives and tried modifying NODE_PATH accordingly:

```
$ find /usr/local/lib -name npmlog # => /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog
$ export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules
$ npm -v   # DIFFERENT PROBLEM - Can't find '../lib/npm.js'
```

At this stage, after more unhelpful googling, I decided I was in over my depth and decided to ask for help. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Comparing the linux files to those on my OSX dev machine where I had been able to install node successfully with brew, I noticed there was one file missing from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm and that was npmrc which contains just "prefix = /usr/local". However, adding this file to Linux had no effect.

Answer (score 30):

It is much faster to do clean NPM reinstall which will remove "broken" links:

```
wget https://npmjs.org/install.sh

chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

Then it will ask you to remove old NPM link

Comment: This is the easiest solution I've found to install both `npm` and `node`. The `n` package makes managing Node.js a breeze.

Comment: this should be the preferred answer

Answer (score 25):

**Using Node Version Manager**

Use a Node version manager like [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to handle installation and version management for you. After you install `nvm` you can simply install any Node version, for example `nvm install 8`.

But if you just want to install the binary yourself, see below:

**Using apt-get**

In special cases where you need a system wide Node installation, you can use apt-get:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

The above snippet will install the latest Node 8.

**Installing the Binary Manually**

In order to install the binary manually, all you need to do is to download the binary and create a bunch of symbolic links. Execute the commands below one after the other, and it should do the job. I have also written a shell script that does it for you if that is easier (see the bottom of the answer). Hope that helps.

**Make sure to use the correct download link for your OS architecture (i.e. either 32-bit or 64-bit) for wget on the second line.**

```
ME=$(whoami) ; sudo chown -R $ME /usr/local && cd /usr/local/bin #adding yourself to the group to access /usr/local/bin
mkdir _node && cd $_ && wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.4/node-v8.11.4-linux-x64.tar.xz -O - | tar zxf - --strip-components=1
ln -s "/usr/local/bin/_node/bin/node" .. # Making the symbolic link to node
ln -s "/usr/local/bin/_node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" ../npm ## making the symbolic link to npm
```

Here is a shell script that downloads and installs all the components. If you use this script to install Node, you can use the uninstall script to uninstall it.

Installing Node

```
#! /bin/bash
# run it by: bash install-node.sh
read -p " which version of Node do you need to install: for example 8.11.4 (or any other valid version): " VERSIONNAME
read -p " Are you using a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system ? Enter 64 or 32: " ARCHVALUE
if [[ $ARCHVALUE = 32 ]]
    then
    printf "user put in 32 \n"
    ARCHVALUE=86
    URL=https://nodejs.org/dist/v${VERSIONNAME}/node-v${VERSIONNAME}-linux-x${ARCHVALUE}.tar.gz

elif [[ $ARCHVALUE = 64 ]]
    then
    printf "user put in 64 \n"
    ARCHVALUE=64
    URL=https://nodejs.org/dist/v${VERSIONNAME}/node-v${VERSIONNAME}-linux-x${ARCHVALUE}.tar.gz

else
    printf "invalid input expted either 32 or 64 as input, quitting ... \n"

    exit
fi

# setting up the folders and the the symbolic links
printf $URL"\n"
ME=$(whoami) ; sudo chown -R $ME /usr/local && cd /usr/local/bin #adding yourself to the group to access /usr/local/bin
mkdir _node && cd $_ && wget $URL -O - | tar zxf - --strip-components=1 # downloads and unzips the content to _node
cp -r ./lib/node_modules/ /usr/local/lib/ # copy the node modules folder to the /lib/ folder
cp -r ./include/node /usr/local/include/ # copy the /include/node folder to /usr/local/include folder
mkdir /usr/local/man/man1 # create the man folder
cp ./share/man/man1/node.1 /usr/local/man/man1/ # copy the man file
cp bin/node /usr/local/bin/ # copy node to the bin folder
ln -s "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" ../npm ## making the symbolic link to npm

# print the version of node and npm
node -v
npm -v
```

Uninstalling Node

```
#! /bin/bash
# run it by: ./uninstall-node.sh
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node/
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/_node/
```

Answer (score 12):

I had a problem like that, but with iojs. However it should be the same procedure:

(Assuming that you've got a file matching `node-v*-linux-x64.tar.gz` in your current directory):

```sh
# In case of iojs you need to replace the occurrences of 'node' with 'iojs'
# Extract the downloaded archive with the linux-x64 version of node
tar zxf node-v*-linux-x64.tar.gz
# Move the extracted folder (./node-v*-linux-x64/) to /opt/
mv ./node-v*-linux-x64/ /opt/
```

To make the binary files available in your shell, create some softlinks inside the `/usr/bin/` directory:

```sh
# Create a softlink to node in /usr/bin/
ln -s /opt/node-v*-linux-x64/bin/node /usr/bin/node
# Create a softlink to npm  in /usr/bin/
ln -s /opt/node-v*-linux-x64/bin/npm  /usr/bin/npm
# Create a softlink to iojs in /usr/bin (this step can be omitted if you're using node)
ln -s /opt/node-v*-linux-x64/bin/iojs /usr/bin/iojs
```

Notice: If you'd like to access the cli of some globally installed node modules (for example `bower`, `typescript` or `coffee-script`), you're required to create a softlink to each of those executables in the `/usr/bin/` directory.

Alternatively you could just add the bin directory of your node installation directory (e.g. `/opt/node-v*-linux-x64/`) to the `PATH` environment variable: (you should use the absolute path for this!)

```sh
# create a new .sh script in /etc/profile.d which adds the directory to PATH
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/opt/node-v0.12.3-linux-x64/bin" > /etc/profile.d/node-npm.sh
```

This change will take effect after logging out and in again.

Both methods worked for me (I use a linux desktop version of Ubuntu 14.04/15.04 with GNOME 3).

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue reported here. Fixed it by removing `/usr/local/bin/npm` and replacing it with a symlink to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/
node
npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js


$ npm -v
1.3.17
```

Answer (score 6):

```
wget <node archive url from nodejs.org>
cd /usr/local
sudo tar --strip-components 1 -xf <path to node archive>
```

You can run node and npm right away.

It used to be documented in the README inside the archive in older versions.

Comment: This is simple, and it works. Consider installing in `/usr` instead of `/usr/local` if you want the binaries to be on the path for the `root` user.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I was able to resolve it by creating symlinks instead of copying the binaries.

```
$ cd /usr/local/src
$ wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.24/node-v0.10.24-linux-x64.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf node-v0.10.24-linux-x64.tar.gz
$ cd node-v0.10.24-linux-x64
$ sudo cp -R lib/* /usr/local/lib
$ sudo cp -R share/* /usr/local/share
$ ln -s /usr/local/src/node-v0.10.24-linux-x64/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
$ ln -s /usr/local/src/node-v0.10.24-linux-x64/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/npm
$ node -v
v0.10.24
$ npm -v
1.3.21
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Minor note: you left out `include` (in addition to `lib` and `share`).

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use [nave](https://github.com/isaacs/nave) to install the binaries. Use wget to download the nave.sh file and then us it to install node. Nave is also nice to have around in case one of your production apps requires a different version of node than what's installed globally.

```
$ wget https://raw.github.com/isaacs/nave/master/nave.sh
$ sudo bash nave.sh usemain 0.10.22
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use GNU stow to make symbolic links of those binaries in /usr/local properly with one command. Stow also allows you to easily remove Node js from /usr/local at a later time and swap multiple versions of Node js.

```
$ # first, install stow
$ mkdir /usr/local/stow # if it doesn't exist
$ # then, place software binary package in /usr/local/stow
$ cd /usr/local/stow
$ stow <package_name>  # install / add sym links
$ source $HOME/.bash_profile  # reload your environment
$ # node -v and npm -v should now work
$ stow -D <package_name> # uninstall / remove sym links
```

These steps worked for me with node-v0.10.17-linux-x64.

Answer (score 1):

In the man page of `cp` in Mac OS X:

> Symbolic links are always followed unless the -R flag is set, in which case symbolic links are not followed, by default.

When you execute `sudo cp bin/* /usr/local/bin`, the symbolic link `bin/npm` is followed.

Actually, `bin/npm` is linked to `../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`, so `cp` will copy `npm-cli.js` to `/usr/local/bin`. That's why you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

The problem is the npm excutable in /usr/local/bin.

The way I solved it was:

`sudo rm /usr/local/bin/npm`

`sudo ln -s "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" /usr/local/bin/npm`

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu there is a `.bashrc` file which sets path to binaries.

By default, there is path set for `bin` in home directory. Perhaps you can create *bin* directory in your *home directory* and move the binaries there. Reboot your system and try executing the command `node`

Comment: Both node (which seems to work fine) and npm (which seems broken) are in /usr/local/bin which is in $PATH, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: This may sound insane, but did you really get the binaries or source. You want binaries right? Make sure you downloaded the binary. Here is the direct link http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.22/node-v0.10.22-linux-x86.tar.gz

Comment: Yes, I did install the binaries. I did try the source earlier, just to confirm gcc 4.1.2 wasn't up to it (and it wasn't). I'm going to have to upgrade to Centos 6 some time, and maybe nows a good time, but dammit I'm sure it's something really simple stopping npm from working.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. So, I *symlinked* **node** and **npm** from `./bin/` to `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested in using Docker, in the Dockerfile,

```
ENV NODE_VERSION 8.10.0
RUN wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz
RUN tar -xJvf node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz -C /usr/local/
ENV NODEJS_HOME /usr/local/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64
ENV PATH $NODEJS_HOME/bin:$PATH

RUN node --version
RUN npm --version
```