# Uninstall nodejs installed from binary distribution files

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have installed nodejs(node-v4.2.1) in ubuntu 14.04 using zip file(tar.gz) downloaded from node js website(not using apt-get install.The location of installed node is **/usr/local/bin**.

while trying to uninstall it using sudo apt-get **purge**,sudo apt-get **remove** &sudo apt-get **autoremove** is **not working**.How could I uninstall it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the solution from the links given below

http://hungred.com/how-to/completely-removing-nodejs-npm/

[How to install node binary distribution files on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028996/how-to-install-node-binary-distribution-files-on-linux)

```
I did the following steps and it works fine


sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node/
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1



cd /home/userName
ls -ld .?* (to display hidden files)
# delete files/folders related with node
sudo rm -f .node_repl_history
sudo rm -rf .npm
```

To Re-install new version follow the below steps

1.Download new version from Node official website.In my case my downloaded file is **node-v6.9.4-linux-x64.tar.xz**

2.Move the file into /usr/local directory using the command

```
sudo mv  Downloads/node-v6.9.4-linux-x64.tar.xz /usr/local
```

3.Use the below command to extract into appropriate directories in /usr/local

```
sudo tar --strip-components 1 -xf node-v6.9.4-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

-xf is to unzip .tar.xz  for tar.gz use -xzf

4.verify installation

```
node --version
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is an uninstall script in the zip, otherwise you need to clean `/usr/local` manually for any node related artefacts.