# Uninstall node from /usr/local/bin/node

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, apt, nvm

I am having a problem uninstalling a package **node** that does not even exists but still shows up in the path, weird it is or am I dumb...
It's contradicting with **nodejs** and I wana get rid of it and install a fresh **node** symlink to **nodejs** so that I have a single source of truth.
So far I have tried most the popular package managers.

*#tag node vs nodejs linux*

```
durrani@ideapad:~ $ nodejs --version
Command 'nodejs' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install nodejs

durrani@ideapad:~ $ node --version
v12.14.0
durrani@ideapad:~ $ which nodejs
durrani@ideapad:~ $ which node   
/usr/local/bin/node
durrani@ideapad:~ $ type node
node is hashed (/usr/local/bin/node)
durrani@ideapad:~ $ type nodejs
bash: type: nodejs: not found
durrani@ideapad:~ $ sudo apt-get remove node
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package node
durrani@ideapad:~ $ sudo apt-get purge node
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package node
durrani@ideapad:~ $ sudo snap remove node
snap "node" is not installed
durrani@ideapad:~ $ sudo pkcon remove node
Resolving                     [=========================]         Package not found: node
Command failed: This tool could not find the installed package: No packages were found
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Got some help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33875362/9486457) and run the following:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node/
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
```

Then I installed nodejs using the official method as mentioned on the [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions-enterprise-linux-fedora-and-snap-packages) website -> [instructions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md)

TL;DR
Run the following:
`12.16.2` being the LTS version as of today.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

The final result I got:

```
durrani@ideapad:~ $ node --version
v12.16.2
durrani@ideapad:~ $ nodejs --version
v12.16.2
durrani@ideapad:~ $ which node
/usr/bin/node
durrani@ideapad:~ $ which nodejs
/usr/bin/nodejs
```

Comment: The instructions also works to update the version. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Very helpful, I had a problem with my first React Native app, and having 2 upgraded versions of node wasn't enough, the third oldest version of node 16.17.0 was the first to and caused to run into a Gradle Daemon error during building `Caused by: java.lang.Exception: React Native needs Node.js >= 18. You're currently on version v16.17.0. Please upgrade Node.js to a supported version and try again.`