# How to update npm and node

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

it is possible that this question is repeated, but it is possible that I had tried all solutions offered (or... that is what i think).

The case is that I am trying to install a phoenix framework (to tinker a little) and it is recommended install all dependencies that uses, and it uses npm for many of them, and when I make npm install, the process works fine until a line that throws this: npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/phoenix_html and after all is a total disaster!!

SOLUTION IS UPDATE NPM AND NODE
The answer for this question is solved [here](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1496). Jose Valim answers that he is using the npm v3.5.2 and node v5.3.0. The problem is that I tried a lot of things, for example I remove and purge node and npm, update and upgrade apt-get and after I install them again and my versions are nodejs v0.10.25 and npm v1.3.10. **That is far from 5.3.0 and 3.5.2**

**MY LAST TRYING**
I tried to make npm install -g npm and qhat I got was this:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-3.9.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-3.9.2.tgz
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@3.9.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
```

It seems as if I get the v3.9.2, but if I do npm -v I get 1.3.10.

Thank you very much.

Comment: delete this question. it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Did you try a source installation from the latest version of the nodejs website?

Comment: @naomik it is a very normal question on stackoverflow, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-node-js-and-npm-to-the-next-versions
(and question has +537 and 189 favs)

Comment: @naomik What? It looks like a perfectly valid programming question to me.

Comment: @naomik The general question is about a system directly related to programming, so at worst it's on the fence, but likely still appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @selten98 tomorrow I´ll try!!

Comment: @EloyFernándezFranco What do you get from `which -a npm`, `npm -g prefix`, and `npm -g root`? It may be that you have multiple installations of NPM on your system. You're using one and updating the other.

Comment: @naomik Delete your remark. It's kind of rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Download one of these here and replace your current nodejs installation with the current build](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/)
If you specifically want 5.3.0 you should be able to get that from GIT somehow.

Go to the nodejs site and do a source installation from one of the available versions is the easiest form I can say it in.

See the script of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028996/how-to-install-node-binary-distribution-files-on-linux)

Comment: Thanks @selten98 I am doing what you say, but still have a problem. I make wget to the node[version].tar.gx file, and after I move all the folders inside to these paths: bin/* to usr/bin; share/* to usr/share; lib/* to /usr/lib; include/* to usr/include; But now, when I do npm -v it throws this error: Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'

Comment: Could you give an update on what operating system you are using?

Comment: Links are not answers.

Comment: @naomik links help

Comment: @selten98 I am using Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: I googled a bit and found that this user seems to have the same problem you have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028996/how-to-install-node-binary-distribution-files-on-linux